Data property always empty when querying Google Safer Browsing API via Google Node.js client
I've written a service for our application which looks up URLs against the Google Safer Browsing API via the official node.js client.
The issue we're encountering is that all URLs that flag with Google Safer Browsing via the browser or Google Transparency report return an empty data object via our service, with the exception of Google's test URL ([http]malware[dot]testing[dot]google[dot]test/testing/malware/*). The HTTP response is '200', which rules out a key misconfiguration.
I've found plenty of examples where others have had the same issue, with no resolution. My service code is shown below:
import { Response } from './interfaces/response';
import { google } from 'googleapis';

export class GoogleSafeBrowsingBaseService {
  protected getReport = async (url: string): Promise<Response> => {
    const safebrowsing = google.safebrowsing({ version: 'v4', auth: process.env.GSB_KEY });

    return safebrowsing.threatMatches
      .find({
        requestBody: {
          client: {
            clientId: process.env.GSB_CLIENT,
            clientVersion: process.env.GSB_VER,
          },
          threatInfo: {
            threatTypes: [
              'MALWARE',
              'SOCIAL_ENGINEERING',
              'UNWANTED_SOFTWARE',
              'POTENTIALLY_HARMFUL_APPLICATION',
            ],
            platformTypes: ['ANY_PLATFORM', 'PLATFORM_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED'],
            threatEntryTypes: ['URL'],
            threatEntries: this.getUrlVariants(url).map((variant) => ({
              url: variant,
            })),
          },
        },
      })
      .then(({ data }) =>
        Object.keys(data).length ? <Response>data : <Response>{ matches: [] },
      );
  };

  private getUrlVariants = (url: string): string[] => {
    const parsedUrl = new URL(url.trim());
    parsedUrl.hash = '';

    if (!parsedUrl.pathname.endsWith('/')) {
      parsedUrl.pathname += '/';
    }

    const results: string[] = [
      `http://${parsedUrl.host}/`,
      `https://${parsedUrl.host}/`,
      `http://${parsedUrl.host}${parsedUrl.pathname}`,
      `https://${parsedUrl.host}${parsedUrl.pathname}`,
    ];

    if (parsedUrl.search) {
      results.push(
        `http://${parsedUrl.host}${parsedUrl.pathname}${parsedUrl.search}`,
        `https://${parsedUrl.host}${parsedUrl.pathname}${parsedUrl.search}`,
      );
    }

    return results;
  };
}


As per documentation, inputted URLs are:

Stripped of fragments, ie #someanchor
URLs are formatted with a trailing slash
Whitespace is stripped (although our controller does already do this)

We've also ensured:

The API key we're using is correctly locked down to our server
The API key is configured for Google's Safer Browsing in Google Cloud Console
The values of GSB_CLIENT, GSB_VER and GSB_KEY do match those of the response object

Any information to resolve this would be gratefully appreciated.
Examples of URLs we've tried with our service, (which at time of writing) do flag up as malicious in some way on Google Transparency Report include:

[http]business[dot]standardcontactverify[dot]com/case/113458020784789 - HTTP 200, empty data property (expected data property populated with object containing the matches)
[http]malware[dot]testing[dot]google[dot]test/testing/malware/* - Google's test URL, HTTP 200 with populated data property (response as expected)
[https]business[dot]verifysecuritypolicy[dot]com/case/113458020784789 - HTTP 200, empty data property (expected data property populated with object containing the matches)


The reason for URLs being formatted as they are is because Stack Overflow flagged my post as potential spam, you get the idea

An immediate test would be to use the credentials (GSB_KEY, GSB_CLIENT, GSB_VER) and construct a request using e.g. curl to verify that your code matches the curl output. This eliminates your code from being the problem.

Yep, sorry I should have put that in the original comment, Yes, the values for each match in the response object. I've updated to reflect this, thanks for pointing out
